# Fragment Resizing How?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How would I resize a fragment when another fragment has been hidden? In other words, when I remove or hide fragment "A" (or listFragment), that space is empty. I need the remaining fragment "B" to resize and fill in the space where fragment "A" was so fragment "B" occupies the full screen. Any help with code examples would be appreciated.  Thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.page_list);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if( this.isVisible ){
        this.isVisible=false;
        ft.hide(frag);
    }else{
         this.isVisible=true;
         ft.show(frag);
    }
    ft.commit();
```

This code will hide the ListFragment with R.id.page_list ID, and the otherone (content) will resize itself automatically.